# Query MYSQL com predominância de cláusula WHERE

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho a seguinte query (após toda logica, ou seja, a query final)

```
SELECT *
FROM cl_assistance AS CA
LEFT JOIN cl_assistance_rel AS CREL ON CA.cod_assistance = CREL.rel_assistance
WHERE latitude
BETWEEN -24.22070591
AND -22.88033389
AND longitude
BETWEEN - 47.30349541
AND - 45.96312339
```

O que preciso de ajuda, é que na tabela `cl_assistance_rel` existe a chave estrangeira rel_type que referencia na `cl_assistance_type` o tipo de assistência.
Então tem 3 opções de suporte que vem no `GET` da requisição "Climatizadores", "Fogões" e "Lavadouras" (em forma de código).

Logo, preciso incluir a query os parâmetros:

```
CREL.rel_type = '1' OR
CREL.rel_type = '2' OR
CREL.rel_type = '3'
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu pego todos os postos dentro da área determinada, depois eu seleciona o os que se encaixam nos tipos de assistências.

No caso se eu juntar essas duas querys, eu acabo pegando todos os postos.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas tente adicionar isto no final: `AND CREL.rel_type IN (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa separar as verificações da query segundo a lógica que descreveu:

> primeiro eu pego todos os postos dentro da área determinada, depois eu
>   seleciona o os que se encaixam nos tipos de assistências

```
SELECT *
FROM cl_assistance AS CA
LEFT JOIN cl_assistance_rel AS CREL ON CA.cod_assistance = CREL.rel_assistance
WHERE 
(latitude
BETWEEN -24.22070591
AND -22.88033389)
AND 
(longitude
BETWEEN - 47.30349541
AND - 45.96312339)
AND
(CREL.rel_type = '1')
```

Essa query vai pegar todas as assistências de determinada área que dá o suporte ao produto 1.